# Using STOMP to receive JMS MapMessages from WildFly 25

Tags: jms, wildfly, stomp

I am using WildFly 25. I want to create a Javascript client using @stomp/stompjs to receive JMS `MapMessage` from the WildFly server. I am receiving the messages, but they are coming through as "isBinaryBody": true with no content. I have read about setting transformation=jms-map-json, but that does not seem to work either. Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: Do you have a documentation reference for the "transformation=jms-map-json" you mentioned?

Comment: Any feedback here?

Answer (score 0):

STOMP is the Simple (or Streaming) **Text** Oriented Message Protocol. A JMS `MapMessage` is specific to JMS. There's no way to automatically translate the map from binary to text in WildFly.